# SSRS Report - Repeat first table header on every page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, pagination, repeat

I have an SSRS report that is made up of 7 tables.  Each table is bound to it's own stored procedure, and they all have the same ID parameter.

The first table is the main information being shown. The other 6 tables are comprised of info related to the main information (contacts, docs, etc).

I'm trying to make sure the header row of the first table, which has the main information about the item that the report is about, gets repeated on every page. I've tried subreports in the same table, but that doesn't paginate correctly in SSRS.  If I have them all as separate tables, I can keep groups together, and get their individual headers to repeat, if they break across a page, but not the header row of the first table, which I would like to do.

It's frustrating, because I would like that table row ideally on the page header, but SSRS won't let you do that. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT --
This is a sample of what the data is like:

Project ABC, Description - A description about the project, Type - Project type DEF, Status - Project Status XYZ

Date started,
Date due,
Date Completed,
Outcome,
Main field 5,
Main field 6,
Main field 7

Project People -
Person 1,
Person 2,
Person 3,

Project Docs -
Doc 1,
Doc 2,
Doc 3

Project Updates -  Update date 1, update notes,
Update date 2, update notes,
Update date 3, update notes,
Update date 4, update notes

I have the project name, description, type and status in 1 table row, with label headers, and I want those 4 fields repeated at the top of every page.  The thing is, each of the other tables have other datasets, because they are connected on the same parameter, but have 1 to many relationships to the project itself. I have no way to know where a page may break, because 1 project may have more docs vs people vs updates etc.

I hope this helps make it make sense.

Comment: I can't picture exactly what your issue is (it's late and I'm old!) but if you had all the data for all datasets in a single dataset, would that solve the problem? If so you can fairly easily accomplish this. If that's an option, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I tried that. It takes forever to load. Basically, there is a name, description, type, and status, for an item.  After that, there is about 20 more fields that come from the same dataset. Then there are 6 more datasets that have a 1 to many relationships to the main info.  I want to repeat those 4 main pieces of info on every page.  I have tried 1 big table, with grouping info, I have tried separate tables inserted into 1 big table, subreports in 1 table. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Could you post some sample (or representative) data from you datasets and what you expect the output to look like (just a mock up) of the first few pages so we can see what you expect on the first page, page breaks etc. I would have thought that simple grouping would work but it sounds like it's more complex so a few samples would be helpful.

Comment: added. I don't know where a page break would happen, but even when I print to PDF (which most will do) I want those 4 fields at the top of every page.

Comment: Have you tired using subreports embedded in a tablix? Then you could could use the tablix header as the repeating subreport.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a single main record and are showing lists of items that relate to that record. If so, you can put fields from the main record in your detail tables' headers by using the `First` function. For example, if you want the `RefNo` field from the MainRecord dataset:

```
=First(Fields!RefNo.Value, "MainRecord")
```

Comment: See my comment above. I am looking to display more than just an ID, but your solution is interesting.  Can I control that it only be visible, if it's the start of a new page?

Comment: You can use the same technique to put the fields into the page's header

Comment: I did that and they show on the first page, but not the 2nd page. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: To add, I made 4 text boxes and put that first expression for each field, from the main dataset, all in the header. It shows at the top of the page when I preview the SSRS report, but when I save to pdf, it doesn't show at all, let along on each page.

Comment: Are you putting them in the [page header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-or-remove-a-page-header-or-footer-report-builder-and-ssrs) and not the table header?

Comment: I've done both, but this latest attempt is textboxes using your expression, in the page header.